# Invalid API parameters

Tags: php, json, api, backend

I created object call API when I set only `"info"` as parameter of method program run without any errors . When I'd set parameter like that ("swapList",$t) I get  `{"error":407,"errorMsg":"Invalid value: currency","time":1476023664,"limit":{"used":5,"allowed":600,"expires":1476024000}}`.I tried a lot of arrays set there but results was the same. Here is API documentation https://github.com/bitmarket-net/api

Here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
class API
{
public function bitmarket_api($method, $params = array())
{
    $key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    $params["method"] = $method;
    $params["tonce"] = time();

    $post = http_build_query($params, "", "&");
    $sign = hash_hmac("sha512", $post, $secret);
    $headers = array(
        "API-Key: " . $key,
        "API-Hash: ". $sign,
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.bitmarket.pl/api2/");  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $ret = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($ret === false)
    {
    die(curl_error($curl));
    }
    echo $ret; 
}
}

$t[]='BTC';
$z =new API;
$z->bitmarket_api('swapList',$t);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the parameters array without key name.

Try with:

```
$t['currency'] = 'BTC';
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.